# In Pandas Groupby, find farthest row under some condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Lets take the following dataframe - Please ignore the output column for input. Output column is the expected output. It is difference in required dates

```
data = [
    ['Group1', 20211129, 'i', 0, 0],
    ['Group1', 20211202, 'r', 465852069, 3],
    ['Group1', 20211202, 'r', 465852070, 3],
    ['Group1', 20211206, 'i', 0, 0],
    ['Group1', 20211213, 'i', 0, 0],
    ['Group2', 20211129, 'i', 0, 0],
    ['Group2', 20211206, 'i', 0, 0],
    ['Group2', 20211210, 'r', 466486129, 11],
    ['Group2', 20211213, 'i', 0, 0],
    ['Group2', 20211227, 'i', 0, 0],
    ['Group2', 20220103, 'i', 0, 0],
    ['Group2', 20220104, 'r', 467650236, 22],
    ['Group2', 20220105, 'r', 467754363, 23]
]
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['group', 'date', 'type', 'rid', 'output'])
data.date = pd.to_datetime(data.date, yearfirst=True, format='%Y%m%d')
data
```

[image]

For each of the record of `type` r, I need to find farthest `type` i in upward direction in each of the `group` but should not cross `type` r. In the above example, for row 1, row 0 is the farthest i. for row 2, again row 0 is the farthest i. For row 7 which is Group, row 5 is the farthest i. For row 11, row 8 is the farthest i as we can not jump an r. For row 12, again row 8 is the farthest i. Final goal is to get the difference between the date fields corresponding to 'r' and the farthest 'i'.

I tried bfill on `rid` but to no success. I think there should be simpler way to achieve this.

Comment: Can you please post the exact output df/series you expect?

Comment: In text is `0, 5, 8` values, what values are in `output` column?

Comment: I updated the question. For 0, 5 and 8 we have to take the date value and getting the difference. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create groups by last `r` consecutive values and in custom function get minimal index of `i` rows:

```
#convert to datetimes
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'], format='%Y%m%d')

#get Trues for last r consecutive values by chain with shifted value with compare i
g = data['type'].eq('r') & data['type'].shift(-1, fill_value='i').eq('i')

def f(x):
    #get only i rows
    m = x['type'].eq('i')
    #filter date if exist else None and assign to new column
    x['out'] =  next(iter(x.loc[m, 'date']), None)
    return x

#pas groups by column group and groups by last r with cumulative sum
data = data.groupby(['group', g.iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1]]).apply(f)
#last get difference with set 0 if not match r
data['out'] = data['date'].sub(data['out']).dt.days.where(data['type'].eq('r'), 0)

print (data)
     group       date type        rid  out
0   Group1 2021-11-29    i          0    0
1   Group1 2021-12-02    r  465852069    3
2   Group1 2021-12-02    r  465852070    3
3   Group1 2021-12-06    i          0    0
4   Group1 2021-12-13    i          0    0
5   Group2 2021-11-29    i          0    0
6   Group2 2021-12-06    i          0    0
7   Group2 2021-12-10    r  466486129   11
8   Group2 2021-12-13    i          0    0
9   Group2 2021-12-27    i          0    0
10  Group2 2022-01-03    i          0    0
11  Group2 2022-01-04    r  467650236   22
12  Group2 2022-01-05    r  467754363   23
```

Comment: Great Solution. But if you can add more explanation about the approach, it would be helpful for many people including me. Thanks.

Comment: @ggaurav - answer was edited.